# How to get python line by line time profiling in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there are an option to see line by line time taken by python code in vscode? Like its there for c++ in visual studio?

Comment: Did you try [python-line-profiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PerpetualHelp.python-line-profiler)? It uses [line-profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) under the hood.